# Why my rgb color in Kivymd looks different to real color?

Tags: python, kivy, python-3.8, rgba, kivymd

I was changing active color of `MDTextFieldRound` in Kivymd.

I set `theme.cls.primary_palette` to `Teal`, and I want to set active color to accent color or lighter color of Teal.

So I searched on Google and found many posts about teal color's accent color. And I want to set color to 102,178,178,1 (https://www.color-hex.com/color-palette/4666).

But when I use this code and run:

```
MDTextFieldRound:
    icon_left: "format-title"
    hint_text: "Set title"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
    width: 500
    size_hint_x: None
    color_active: 102,178,178,1
```

I can see just white color when active like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sqNn.jpg).
I also tried 0,76,76,1, but then I can see just skyblue color.

Why this happens? And how to use exact color with RGB in kivymd?

I'm using Python 3.8 and Windows 10. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colors in Kivy are lists of values from 0 to 1. To get those values just divide values that are between 0 and 255 by 255. So you teal becomes `102/255,178/255,178/255,1` or:

```
color_active: 0.4, 0.698, 0.698, 1
```